# How to hide the Smiley and the no of likes in the No of Likes field in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, office-365, jquery

I am having a list 10 Items. Now I had enabled a like feature that is available in SharePoint 2013. I get the responses from the people by no of likes.

I want to hide the Smiley and the no of likes count displayed as that needs to be displayed only for the admin group and all others only they can like or unlike the items.

Answer (score 1):

You try by adding script editor webpart on the page and add below script :

```
<style type="text/css">
.likecount {
 display:none;
}

.LikeSection {
 display:none;
 }
</style>
```

Add if class name does not matches with your control class you check it by inspecting the element in browser and replace the above class name (.likecount is class name of the control)